# Please, explain what %w means

Tags: ruby

I don't understand "%W" - what does that mean?

```
string[index].capitalize! unless %w(the and over).include?(string[index])
```

Comment: Your question asks what `%W` means (uppercase "W"), but your example uses `%w` (lowercase "w"). They mean subtly different things, so which do you want to know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%w` creates an array based on the words in it (whitespace separated).

So

```
%w(the and over)
```

Will become

```
["the", "and", "over"]
```

It is a commonly used method in ruby.

So a portion of your string will be capitalized, unless that portion is either "the", "and" or "over".

Answer (score 1):

Check [`%Q, %q, %W, %w, %x, %r, %s`](http://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/).

This would help you a lot.